# Two slides at once

Tags: beamer

What package is used to make slides like these:
http://cr.yp.to/talks/2015.01.12/slides-djb-20150112-4x3.pdf

It's two vertical slides at a time in a split screen format.

Comment: I would say this is more complex than what you say, since three parts of slides appear on some page (e.g. p. 4).

Comment: I don't know how it WAS made, but one could reproduce it using texpower, pdfscreen and pdfpages and a lot of work.

Comment: Maybe it looks better in Adobe. But in my viewer, I can only wonder why anybody would try to create something like that deliberately.